# Non-Windows equivalents of NetTCPIP module

Tags: debian, powershell

Functions such as [Get-NetIPAddress](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipaddress?view=win10-ps) are available on Windows Powershell, but the the NetTCPIP module is not present or available for Debian. What is the canonical and portable way to get this functionality? I am obviously aware that I can call `ifconfig` and parse the results, but that is not "the Powershell way" which expects to manipulate objects rather than strings, and would not be portable back to Windows anyway!

Comment: Your version of PowerShell is controlled by the version of .Net it supports.  WinPS, is full .Net whereas PSv6x and higher is .Net Core. So, until they bring full parity of full .Net to .Net Core you will not see full parity (backwards compatibility- and it's being worked on) to PSCore.